# assign iteration time in conways game of life

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

Hi I am writing a code of Conway's game of Life. I need to assign 0.5 seconds iteration time here. The matrix should be updated in every 0.5 seconds. How to assign 0.5 second iteration time here? I thought of using a timer. But how to implement this? My code is as follows:

```
/*
 * pp1.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 21.09.2016
 *      Author: fislam
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

void copy(int array1[10][10],int array2[10][10])
{ for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
              {for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                  array2[j][i]=array1[j][i];
              }
              }
void life(int array[10][10])
{ int temp[10][10];
copy (array,temp);
for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
  {      for (int i=0;i<1;i++)
      { int count=0;
      count=array[j-1][i]+
            array[j-1][i-1]+
            array[j][i-1]+
            array[j+1][i-1]+
            array[j+1][i]+
            array[j+1][i+1]+
            array[j][i+1]+
            array[j-1][i+1];
      if(count<2||count>3)
          temp[j][i]=0;
      if (count==2)
          temp[j][i]=array[j][i];
      if (count==3)
          temp[j][i]=1;



}
}copy (temp,array);
}
void print(int array[10][10])
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(array[j][i] == 1)
                cout << '*';
            else
                cout << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a synchronous or an asynchronous timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between two calls into `life`, insert a [this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) with a 500 miliseconds

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{500});
```

If you prefer C-style, use [usleep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html)

Don't forget to include the necessary headers.

Something like:

```
int main() {
  // how may iteration of 'life'
  const int MAX_ITER=100;
  int world[10][10];

  // set your world to the initial configuration
  // ....

  for(int i-0; i<MAX_ITER; i++) {
    life(world);
    print(world);
    // wait for half a second
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{500});
  } 
}
```

Comment: Exactly in which place?Sorry I am new in this topic.

Comment: @TamannaIslam You didn't post all your code. The l`life` function is supposed to do a single iteration of life. To have the entire evolution, you will need to call it repeatedly in some place.

Comment: Hi, Thank you.The rest part of the code is lengthy that's why I didn't paste it here

Comment: This answer is pretty good, but can be made better by using `sleep_until` instead.  Get a `steady_clock::now()` at the start of the iteration and add `500ms` to that.  Then at the end of the iteration `sleep_until` that `time_point`.  If the "work" in the loop takes `xms`, use of `sleep_for(500ms)` causes each iteration to take `(x + 500)ms`.  With `sleep_until(tp)`, each iteration will take `500ms`.

Comment: "With sleep_until(tp), each iteration will take 500ms"... of course, unless the work inside the loop take longer than 500ms.